# Grabbing title as fileName but returning none

Tags: python, web-scraping

Trying to grab the title of the img to make it the filename once saved. Keeps returning none and overwriting the file.

```py
 irock = (soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container"))

        for img in irock:
            imageElement = img.find("img")
            bingo = imageElement.get("data-src")

        for title in irock:
            fileName = title.get('title')

            imgName = fileName

            fullName = str(imgName) + ".jpg"

            urllib.request.urlretrieve(bingo, fullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Needed to search the img class to find title.

```
with open('urlList10.txt') as inf:
    urls = [line.strip() for line in inf]

    for url in urls:
        sourceCode = requests.get(url)
        plainText = sourceCode.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plainText, "html.parser")
        irock = soup.find_all('div', class_="card-img-container")

        for img in irock:
            imageElement = img.find("img")
            bingo = imageElement.get("data-src")
            imgName = imageElement.get("title")
            fullName = str(imgName) + ".jpg"
            r = urllib.request.urlretrieve(bingo, fullName)
```

Comment: you don't need that last loop.  You already have everything you need to determine imgName, fullName  and to do the request.

Comment: Are you going to do something with the return from _urllib.request.urlretrieve(bingo, fullName)_   ?  Last line?  It needs an assignment. And everything within the _with_ needs indenting (only just noticed that )

Comment: No worries. Thank you.

Comment: Any chance you could look at the timeout error im getting on my recent post

Comment: I think you wanted a list comprehension here: _urls = [line.strip() for line in inf]_  see if that works as expected. Otherwise, I see why you used the () I think - you were after a generator.